# create array and get value in array Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to create array and which I am creating in loop but I want that array to be declared out of the loop.This to be done in shopify: I am using:

```
{% assign productid="" %}
  {% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
  {% assign product =  product.id | split: ", " %} 
{% endfor %}
{{product}} // should return value 3,4,4 but not returning
```

My explanation is not good But I tried my best to explain .Please can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 5):

you have 2 ways to get that:

```
1:
{% assign productids = "" %}
    {% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
      {% assign productids =  productids | append: product.id | append: ',' %} 
    {% endfor %}
<p>{{ productids }}</p>
```

...

```
2:
{% assign productids = collections.frontpage.products | map: 'id' %}
{% for pid in productids %}
    <p>{{ pid }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to create an array of product ids?

You could do that like:

```
{% assign productids = collections.frontpage.products | map: 'id' %}
{{ productids |join: ','}}
```